# Querying documents irrespective timezone mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timezone

I have a few documents having the date saved in different timezones offset.
like

```
[
    {
        "ac":ISODate("2019-09-09T18:30:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "ac":ISODate("2019-09-09T12:00:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "ac":ISODate("2019-09-09T10:00:00.000Z")
    },
]
```

Now what i am trying to do is, query documents based on the date.

let's say if I pass date as `IST 9-9-2019`, my intention is to find all the documents which were created on `IST 9-9-2019` irrespective of the timezone.

I tried converting the date to UTC but no luck

```
const date = "2019-09-08T18:30:00.000Z";
model.find({
    ac: {
        $gte: moment(date).utc().startOf('day'),
        $lte: moment(date).utc().endOf('day'),
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We have $dateToString operation in MongoDB, we can use that in aggegation and convert it to string and then compare it to the date.